# Sudden spike of ANRs the last few days, trace doesn't have any of my code in it. How do I go about troubleshooting this?

Tags: android, android-anr-dialog

I've had a sudden spike of ANRs lately, seems like October 5th is when they really started spiking up. They are affecting my latest release that is from around that date but they are also affecting my previous release that is from earlier in September. For that earlier release I can see that the ANRs really started on the 5th.

For my top two ANR traces, I don't see a single line that involves my code and the info in them isn't really useful. I'm including a full screen printout of one of the traces, they are all a bit different but they have some of the same stuff. Particularly I noticed most of them have a gms measurement call going on. While I haven't updated gms recently.

So my question is, how do I go about troubleshooting a trace like this?

Trace link https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjuyl.jpg

Thanks.

Comment: You need to start with  the state of the Main Thread. You can see that the main thread is in " WAITING" state. Figure out what is causing the main thread to be waiting.

Comment: For how to read traces check this blog [link](http://elliotth.blogspot.com/2012/08/how-to-read-dalvik-sigquit-output.html). And try StrictMode [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html).

Comment: I should mention I have never gotten this ANR myself. I do run with StrictMode often. The ANRs started on code that didn't have the ANRs with zero changes, meaning a release that had been out for a couple of weeks with nowhere near that volume of ANRs. I also have zero remote code of my own so it isn't like I can make them happen remotely. I will check that link, thanks.

Comment: @Dinesh how do I know what it is waiting on? I see a lock but how do I know what is running synchronized on that same object? keep in mind I don't have a way to reproduce this, only happens on the Play Store console.

Comment: @casolorz : Try finding something associated with your app package in the Trace. One thing that's sure is that this ANR is happening during app launch since you can see zygote reference in the main thread.  Wat is happening during app launch ? Any access to disk ? Any API call ?  Any SDK initialisation ??

Answer (score 2):

Here is are couple of clues from the Traces:

1. CountDown latch is used. So one of those threads, that is using latch is taking a long time to complete. That is causing the Main thread to be blocked.
2. Shared Preferences is being edited
3. A service is being stopped

Is there something of this phenomenon thats happening in your app?
"A service is being stopped, and shared preferences is being edited".

***Countdown latch :*** 
*A java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch is a concurrency construct that allows one or more threads to wait for a given set of operations to complete.
A CountDownLatch is initialized with a given count. This count is decremented by calls to the countDown() method. Threads waiting for this count to reach zero can call one of the await() methods. **Calling await() blocks the thread until the count reaches zero**.*

@casolorz : Debugging ANR is a challenge. The ANR trace you have is just the state of all threads in your Application Process when the ANR has occurred. It is not as straight forwards as debugging a crash.

Here are some ways that you can debug

**Method 1**

1. See the state of the Main Thread.
2. If the main thread is Waiting, then figure out what is making it wait. It may be some other thread that is making it to wait. You can find out the culprit by tracking down the thread identifier. You might see something like "Waiting because of a resource held by Thread tid= ". tid should help you to navigate to the culprit.
3. With tid, you can follow the trail as long as possible till you reach a dead end.

If method 1 does not give you a headway, try this

**Method 2 :** Come up with a Hyphothesis.

Find out whats happening to the Main thread
In your case, the app is getting launched. You can see Zygote getting initialised, which confirms this hypothesis.

Once you know that the ANR is happening at App launch, see what is happening at app launch which would relate to I/O or Network.

This could be like accessing a SharedPreference which is quiet heavy(Say 1 mb which is a bad thing. You need to consider making the shared pref thin).

Or this could be an SDK that you are initialising. You can profile your code using Traces, and this would give you a fair idea of something that is taking a long time to execute.

Sometime this might be totally unrelated to your application. I have seen this occur.

Debugging ANR's are quiet challenging and its interesting too.

Comment: Thank you for all that info. I will have to do some deep analysis. I'm guessing since it changed after the code was live that something else changed outside of the code that is causing this, probably Google Play Services related since that is the one thing that often updates and the code depends on.

Answer (score 0):

1.) It may be because of you are running SharedPreferences apply() method very frequently which are spanning so many threads and all threads are trying to write to the same shared preference file which are queued and while onPause() method is called all these operations are blocking to finish which is causing ANR.

2.) If you are using commit() for Shared Preferences then it will be blocking call on main thread for all previous apply() asynchronous operations for the same SharedPreference which may cause ANR on main thread.

3.) May be some big data is saved in Shared Preference because of which other commit()/apply() are placed in queue and waiting for their turn to write to the I/O file and can cause ANR once onPause() is called since all these commit() and apply() operations need to be finished before onPause() finished.